# Why can't I pass cend() and cbegin() to count_if?

Tags: c++, constants, countif

I am trying to count the number of strings whose length is greater than 6 in a vector. This is pretty simple but I am trying to do it using the `count_if` in the `algorithm` library. So here's my code:

```
int string_size_check(const std::vector<std::string> &v, unsigned int size){
    return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [size] (std::string &s)->bool{ return s.size() > size; });
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "abc", "abcd", "abcde", "abcdef", "abcdefg", "abcdefg" };
    std::cout << string_size_check(v, 6);
}
```

`string_size_check` is the function for that. I used a lambda for the predicate.
This code did not compile. The problem was with the `const` in the first parameter. `begin` and `end` will return `const` iterators when it is called on a `const` vector. So it's effectively `cbegin` and `cend` When I remove the `const` it works. I made the parameter `const` because AFAIK count_if does not change the contents in the container.
I have no idea why passing `const` iterators to count_if will not work.
**EDIT: Here is the error message** in visual studio 2013

```
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm(97): error C2664: 'bool string_size_check::<lambda_fed0cfd76fd966b8c62fe345d7e88af2>::operator ()(std::string &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'std::string &'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm(109) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::iterator_traits<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *>::difference_type std::_Count_if<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>*,_Pr>(_InIt,_InIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Pr=string_size_check::<lambda_fed0cfd76fd966b8c62fe345d7e88af2>
1>  ,            _InIt=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\enter\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\win32test\win32test\source.cpp(7) : see reference to function template instantiation '__w64 int std::count_if<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>,string_size_check::<lambda_fed0cfd76fd966b8c62fe345d7e88af2>>(_InIt,_InIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>
1>  ,            _Pr=string_size_check::<lambda_fed0cfd76fd966b8c62fe345d7e88af2>
1>          ]
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are right that since your `vector` is `const`, your iterators are also going to be  `const`.

But consequently, the parameter of the predicate function must also be `const`.

You need: `const std::string &s`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. I spent a lot of time checking the code. I wish error messages were more clear

Comment: @emper `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'std::string &'` says it.  It does give a strange name for `std::string` (the basic string thing), as `std::string` is a typedef.

Comment: It still look very unclear to me, as it does not refer to const, which was the issue. (By refer, I mean the literal english refer ;)

Comment: @EmpereurAiman [clang reports](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dd052d3ec179429): "1st argument (blahblahblah) would lose const qualifier". Compilers change much regarding this topic, for me clang is the best one currently.

Comment: Looks great, I think I will use clang with visual studio IDE.